# How to add an object from an ArrayList to another ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I have two classes Student and ClassRoom, each class has an ArrayList. I'm trying to move a student object from students ArrayList to ClassRoom ArrayList but it is not working.

ClassRoom class code:

```
public class ClassRoom{

private String id;
private String name;
private int age;
ArrayList< ClassRoom >classRoom;

public ClassRoom(String id, String name, int age){

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public ClassRoom() {
    classRoom = new ArrayList();
    id = " ";
    name = " ";
    age = 0;
}

public void Add(String id,String name,int age){
    ClassRoom c = new ClassRoom(id, name, age);
    classRoom.add(c);
}
```

Student class code:

```
public class Student{

private String id;
private String name;
private int age;
private ClassRoom classroom;

ArrayList< Student >students;

public Student(String id, String name, int age){

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public Student() {
    students = new ArrayList();
    id = " ";
    name = " ";
    age = 0;
}

public void Add(String id,String name,int age){
    Student s = new Student(id, name, age);
    students.add(s);
}

public void MoveToClassRoom(String id, String name, int age){
    for(int i=0; i< students.size();i++){
                if (students.get(i).getId().equals(id)){
                classroom.Add(students.get(i).getId(), students.get(i).getName(), students.get(i).getAge());
                students.remove(i);
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Student is not a ClassRoom so it cannot fit to ClassRoom list (even if the student can fit into a room).

Comment: Objects (including ArrayLists) aren't "in" classes.

Comment: Do you really want each `Student` to have an `ArrayList<Student>` as a member? It seems like just `id`, `name`, and `age` would be the good members of `Student`.  Similarly, should `ClassRoom` have an `ArrayList<ClassRoom>`? It seems like `ClassRoom` should only need an `ArrayList<Student>` and not have `id`, `name`, and `age`. I know this isn't really answering your exact question but if these are issues it might make things less confusing if you fix them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Students` are not kinds of `Classroom`. Because you're using a couple of `ArrayList`s that are specific to both kinds, there's little interchangability. The reason for this is because every object that resides in a `List` must somewhere along the line share the same chain of inheritance that matches the `List`'s type.

In Java, every class you create implicitly inherits from a type `Object`. This is where the `toString()` and `hashCode()` methods comes from, for example. So if you wanted to put `Student` and `Classroom` in the same list, you could place them in a `List` of type `<Object>`... but there's nothing *too* interesting you'd be able to do with that. It would however highlight the point that you'd be able to perform types of interactions with elements of that list that are generic enough to support all contained elements; i.e. you could call `Object` methods on any element within the `List`.

So, maybe you'd be interested in a slightly different design pattern, if you wanted to do something more application-specific with it's contents. If you want to place multiple kinds of objects within the same `List`, there must be some kind of shared functionality that you want; some case where it seems logical to treat a `Student` in the same way as you would a `Classroom`. If you wanted to do this, you could have both `Student` and `Classroom` `extend` a `class` of type `SchoolEntity`, which would contain methods and properties which both `Student` and `Classroom` elements would need. Then you could create a `List` of type `<SchoolEntity>`, to hold both kinds or even more.

For greater flexibility, you could define an interface `ISchoolEntity`, which both `Student` and `Classroom` could implement, and use a `List<ISchoolEntity>` instead. The reason this is more flexible is because Java doesn't support multiple `inheritance`; this means that once `Classroom` and `Student` `extend` `SchoolEntity`, there'd be no way later they'd also be able to `extend` another class like `CollegeEntity`. Conversely, Java allows a class to implement many kinds of interface, so a `Student` and `Classroom` could be potentially be treated as both kinds of `ISchoolEntity` and `ICollegeEntity`, if the application required it later on.